# How to import a variable from a (ba)sh-script?

Tags: python, linux, bash, variables, import

I'd like to do something like this:

```
from ./script.sh import VARIABLE # <-- python style
```

(without changing `script.sh`)

Comment: this is not possible as you have described it. you could export the variable, but it would likely require modifying your script.

Comment: is the importing script python or bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly the same thing, but this works:

```
source ./script.sh
echo "VARIABLE=${VARIABLE}."
```

Shorter form:

```
. ./script.sh
echo "VARIABLE=${VARIABLE}."
```

This might not be desired as this will execute any code that is not in functions inside script.sh.